# Android - How to run full method before triggering TextWatcher?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have two EditText-views using the same TextWatcher.
I can input text to these manually, one by one. This triggers the TextWatcher for each individual input - and that's good. However, there is also a method which does will change the text in both of these EditText-views. I want this to trigger the watcher just once, but currently it gets triggered twice. My code looks something like this.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
editText2.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);

private void myMethod(String firstText, String secondText) {
    editText1.setText(firstText); //This triggers watcher 
    editText2.setText(secondText); //And this triggers watcher once again
}
```

So essentially, what I want to do is call myMethod and then have the TextWatcher do stuff once myMethod has run and both editText1 and editText2 has been changed. 
However, I still want to maintain TextWatcher's ability to "hear" then I input text to any of these EditTexts manually. How can I achieve this?

Any pushes in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a boolean as -

```
boolean BLOCK = false;
```

and

```
private void myMethod(String firstText, String secondText) {
    BLOCK = true;
    editText1.setText(firstText); //Watcher won't be triggered first time
    BLOCK = false;
    editText2.setText(secondText); //Watcher will be triggered now

}
```

now in onTextChange Method do as

```
void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
  if(!BLOCK){
      // your code 
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the simplest answer in my case. However, I believe it should be: `private void myMethod(String firstText, String secondText) {
    BLOCK = true;
    editText1.setText(firstText);                                                         
    BLOCK = false; 
    editText2.setText(secondText);    
}`

Comment: Yes you can do as you want

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

you can first set null `addTextChangedListener` to your editext than when you call `myMethod` than set `addTextChangedListener` to your edittext like below sample code

```
// set null TextChangedListener to your editText
editText1.addTextChangedListener(null);
editText2.addTextChangedListener(null);
myMethod("Nilu","Neel");

private void myMethod(String firstText, String secondText) {
    editText1.setText(firstText); //This triggers watcher 
    editText2.setText(secondText); //And this triggers watcher once again
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);// set here your TextWatcheroriginal 
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);/ set here your TextWatcheroriginal 
}
```

**EDIT**

> setText without triggering text watcher

You need unregister your `TextWatcher` while you use `setText` and , and then re-register it as per your requirement .

Comment: Thanks, but what will happen if I want to manually input text into my EditTexts? In this case, the Watcher will not "hear" that, will it?

Comment: @Zerato can u explain more

Comment: he means he wants to setText without triggering text watcher :p (while he manually sets text) @NileshRathod

Comment: The two EditTexts can be inputted to manually, one by one. This should trigger the TextWatcher for each individual input. However, there is also a method which does a calculation and sets the text of BOTH EditTexts automatically. This should tirgger the TextWatcher ONCE.

Comment: @Zerato you can also remove textwatcher after your work done.

Comment: Yeah then add it later on again @Zerato basically clear and add !!

Comment: @SantanuSur same thing i did in above ans

Comment: For this to work, I believe I need to declare my TextWatcher globally. Is that generally a good thing to do?

Comment: @Zerato yes no problem with that